# Как в приложение на golang вставить другой бинарник?

Tags: golang

Можно ли в приложение golang вставить другой бинарный файл и в определенное время его запустить?

Comment: А какой смысл то?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно немного детальнее описать задачу: 
Нужно ли вам запускать подпрограмму отдельным процессом? 
Если да, то ваш путь: положить оба бинарника в Docker и через os.Exec выполнить подпрограмму.

Если не нужно запускать отдельным процессом, а просто хочется вызвать какую-то функцию, то вам нужна статическая линковка: https://github.com/shadowmint/go-static-linking